# Detecting mouse clicks for SDL_Surfaces in SDL2

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I wanna make a program where if you select a surface it gets put in the selectedPiece variable, but I'm using SDL_PointInRect. And it gives this error "the argument of type "SDL_Surface" is incompatible with parameter of type "const SDL_Rect"" Do you know alternatives to PointInRect that are compatible with Surfaces?

```
SDL_Surface* selectedPiece;
std::list<SDL_Surface*> pieces;

bool leftClick;

if (SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN)
{
    if (!leftClick && windowEvent.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)
    {
        leftClick = true;

        for (auto surface : pieces 
        {
            if (SDL_PointInRect(&mousePos, surface)) //<<<--- the sdl point in rect isnt compatible with the surface
            {
                selectedPiece = surface;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the definitions of `pieces` and `selectedPiece`. Don't have us guessing.

Comment: currently the pieces is a list of rects, which i want to be a list of surfaces and selected piece is another rect. i want both of them to be surfaces but i would need a list of surfaces and i dont know how to make that

Comment: How do you create a list of rects and why doesn't it seem to work to create a list of `SDL_Surface`s in the same way? Show your attempt at least.

Comment: this: std::list<SDL_Rect *> rectangles;

Comment: Ok, not that I think it's a good idea to keep pointers in the `std::list` but, what happens if you do that with `SDL_Surface*`? Please describe the problem - and update your question with the information.

Comment: Oh my god im so stupid, the problem wasnt the list of sdl surfaces but the thing is i hadnt included #include <list>, thats why it wasnt working. sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: but the SDL_PointInRect isnt working now so is there any other alternative to that for surfaces?

Comment: You need to ask a new question where you clearly describe the problem you have with `SDL_PointInRect`. I'm voting to close this question as a typo.

Comment: If you get a compiler error, you should always include it in your question.

Comment: the argument of type "SDL_Surface" is incompatible with parameter of type "const SDL_Rect" is the error i get now

Comment: @AseedusSluginas You should ask a new question _or_ edit the current question instead of writing details here in the comments. Create a [mre] so we can see the definitions and what you are trying to do etc.

Comment: Regarding your updated question: A surface doesn't have a position. How are you using the surfaces? Are you using `SDL_BlitSurface`? If so, what argument do you give as `SDL_BlitSurface`'s  fourth argument? Use the same with `SDL_PointInRect`.

Comment: i do use blit surface and i give the arguments SDL_BlitSurface(imageSurface, NULL, windowSurface, NULL)

Comment: What do you mean by _"i need the image on the surface"_? You wanted to test if the cursor in the rectangle that your surface covers, right? Since you paint your surface at (0,0), the proper test is to do as I suggest in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you `SDL_BlitSurface(imageSurface, NULL, windowSurface, NULL);` it means that the destination rectangle's top left corner is at (0,0).

The proper check would then be:

```cpp
SDL_Rect surfacerect{0, 0, surface->w, surface->h};

if (SDL_PointInRect(&mousePos, &surfacerect))
```